# Is adding AddMvc() Service twice in ConfigureServices() a good practice in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, service, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget, configure

I'm creating a Nuget Package for Asp.Net Core. I want to make it simple to configure. So I decided to give a fluent way approach to add my Nuget to the service collection in `ConfigureServices()` in Asp.Net Core.

This is what I'm planning to do:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options => options....);

    services.AddMyNugetPackageName();
}
```

Inside my `AddMyNugetPackageName()` method,

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyNugetPackageName(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc(options => options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyModelBinderProvider()))
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

    return services;
}
```

So now if people start using my Nuget package, will the `AddMvc()` inside my `AddMyNugetPackageName()` replace the `AddMvc()` in their `ConfigureServices()`? Will this cause any trouble to the end users?

If this will replace the user's `AddMvc()` in their `ConfigureServices()` then what is the best approach or how to handle this?

Comment: I'd say this is not good practice. Technically it's not going to be a problem because you're just adding services, but it does mean the extra MVC bits you are configuring are hidden away from the user and may cause confusion. It looks like you are just adding a JSON contract resolver and a custom model binder, why not just add those two things?

Comment: @DavidG Yeah even I'm thinking of better approach!!. Please could you assist me on how this can be made better? I'm also adding `services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();` inside my `AddMyNugetPackageName()`. So how can this be implemented in a better way? This is what I thought instead of asking my end user to add these three items in `ConfigureServices()` I thought it would be better if I give a fluent approach

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `IConfigureOptions` pattern to inject a `MvcOptions` configuration from your nuget package

```
public class MyConfigureOptions : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0,new MyModelBinderProvider());
    }
}
```

Use `ConfigureOptions` to register your options

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyNugetPackageName(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureOptions<MyConfigureOptions>();
}
```

Add your nuget services to the service collection

```
services.AddMvc();
services.AddMyNugetPackageName();
```

Comment: Hi @shoe. Thanks for teaching me a new technique. How to add `AddJsonOptions()` in `MyConfigureOptions`? Do I need to inherit another interface like `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, IConfigureOptions<MvcJsonOptions>` and have two `Configure(MvcOptions options)` and `Configure(MvcJsonOptions options)`?

Comment: Yes it's a different type you want to configure so create a new configOptions class and another call to `ConfigureOptions`

Comment: Yeah that's how I ended up doing. Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: Deos this "add" to existing `MvcOptions` or "replace" them?

Comment: Worth adding that you can use `services.Configure<MvcOptions>(o => { ..... });` if you don't want to create a new class to configure the options